# Error when trying to use NuGet in WebMatrix 3

Tags: asp.net, nuget, webmatrix

When clicking the "NuGet" button in WebMatrix, I get this error. I've tried re-installing WebMatrix, and re-installing NuGet from the extension gallery.
The extension gallery also tells me there's no update, so I can't update it either.

```
An error occurred.

The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages' is incompatible with version 2.5.40416.9020 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

System.InvalidOperationException: The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages' is incompatible with version 2.5.40416.9020 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
   ved NuGet.Manifest.CheckSchemaVersion(XDocument document)
   ved NuGet.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, IPropertyProvider propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackage.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)
   ved NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsureManifest()
   ved NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage..ctor(IFileSystem fileSystem, String packagePath)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.OpenPackage(String path)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.GetPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String path)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.<>c__DisplayClass9.<FindPackage>b__5(String path)
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
   ved NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)
   ved NuGet.DataServicePackage.EnsurePackage(IPackageCacheRepository cacheRepository)
   ved NuGet.DataServicePackage.GetSupportedFrameworks()
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SupportsTargetFrameworks>b__29(FrameworkName t)
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.SupportsTargetFrameworks(IEnumerable`1 targetFramework, IPackage package)
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass27.<GetUpdatesCore>b__23(IPackage candidate)
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   ved System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.GetUpdatesCore(IPackageRepository repository, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeAllVersions, IEnumerable`1 targetFramework, IEnumerable`1 versionConstraints)
   ved NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.GetUpdates(IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeAllVersions, IEnumerable`1 targetFrameworks, IEnumerable`1 versionConstraints)
   ved NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.GetUpdates(IPackageRepository repository, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeAllVersions, IEnumerable`1 targetFrameworks, IEnumerable`1 versionConstraints)
   ved NuGet.WebMatrix.WebProjectManager.GetPackagesWithUpdates(String searchTerms, Boolean filterPreferredPackages)
   ved NuGet.WebMatrix.NuGetPackageManager.GetPackagesWithUpdates()
   ved NuGet.WebMatrix.NuGetModel.GetPackagesWithUpdates()
   ved NuGet.WebMatrix.FilterManager.GetUpdatePackages()
   ved System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   ved System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon, click the Gallery button.When the NuGet Gallery is displayed, just change the defalut package source type (WebMatrix Package Source) to NuGet Official Package Source.

Comment: I can't seem to use the library when I retrieve it from there, though.
I am following [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/intro-to-web-pages-programming) tutorial.